# Do I need to release a constant NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring, literals

I'm reading memory management rules to this point where it said

```
- (void)printHello {

    NSString *string;

    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);

    [string release];

}
```

you have ownership and have to release `string`, but I'm curious about the `@"Hello"`. `@" "` is the syntax for creating and `NSString`, and it's an object. So doesn't that get leaked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@"…"` is a literal instance of `NSString`. When the compiler sees a literal string, it maps the string into the binary file (e.g. your program) and the string is available as an `NSString` object when the binary is loaded (e.g. when you run your program). You don’t have to manage the memory occupied by literal strings because they’re an intrinsic part of your binary — they are always available, they never get released, and you don’t have to worry about managing their memory.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Is there any place in Apple docs to read about this? I couldn't find anything in NSString documentation.

Comment: @Nikita I’m not sure where that’s documented. I personally noticed that when I inspected the reference count of a literal string and it returned `NSUIntegerMax`. That’s how the runtime indicates that an object is never released. If I find any documentation about this, I’ll post it here.

Comment: @Nikita I haven’t found anything official but if you search for questions with `nsstring retain count` on Stack Overflow you’ll see answers similar to mine and written by Apple folks.

Comment: @Nikita The documentation for `-retainCount` does say that ‘For objects that never get released (that is, their release method does nothing), this method should return UINT_MAX, as defined in <limits.h>.’

Answer (score 1):

Bavarious's answer is correct. For the curious, I can add that this is documented in Apple's “String Programming Guide”, specifically the section “[Creating Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-SW1)” where it says (emphasis mine):

> The simplest way to create a string object in source code is to use the Objective-C `@"..."` construct:
>
> `NSString *temp = @"/tmp/scratch";`
>
> Note that, when creating a string constant in this fashion, you should use UTF-8 characters. *Such an object is created at compile time and exists throughout your program’s execution. The compiler makes such object constants unique on a per-module basis, and they’re never deallocated.*