# NSString alloc / release / retain

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

`a` is an instance of `NSString`. I thought if I print a string after releasing it, it will crash the app. Instead it returned proper value assigned to it. My question is, shall we get the value of an object even after releasing it? If not, why I am able to see the value of `a`, even after it is deallocated?

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *a;
}

@end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    a=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"abc"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"String %@",a);
    [a release];
    NSLog(@"release %@",a);
    [a retain];
    NSLog(@"retain %@",a); 
}
```

**Output:-**

```
2012-08-24 14:15:49.501 a[1176:f803] string abc
2012-08-24 14:15:53.404 a[1176:f803] release abc
2012-08-24 14:15:55.325 a[1176:f803] retain abc
```

Comment: I assume a is a property of your controller, how is it defined?

Comment: you are not quite sure after the releasing you can access the object. it depends on when the memory of the original object will be overridden. when you are lucky you can access the object when you are unlucky the application is crashed. **it is high risk to try to work with any object after you release them.**

Comment: Thank You holex. Was just trying it out.. Thank u waldrumpus :)

Comment: Also note the following implementation detail: passing a string literal as the argument to `initWithString` will return a pointer to the same string literal, since NSString is inmutable. String literals get allocated statically and never get deallocated.

Comment: Wow.. albertamg!!! i tried it out with `NSMutableString` and it crashes.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@"abc"` is a constant, so it will never be released

feel the difference:

```
a = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 123];
```

it gives for me crash or **release main** output since it refers to some chunk of memory

Comment: Will it crash if I use `a = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@“%@", abc];` where abc is another string??

Comment: @holex But it is mentioned here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769769/do-i-need-to-release-a-constant-nsstring, It will stay in memory even after we release the NSString instance. Doesn’t that mean, its a constant? Or kinda that?

Answer (score 3):

Releasing any object means that the caller is done with it. After the release, the results of trying to access the object are undefined - could be a crash, could be that someone else is retaining the object and it works without crashing, could be something else entirely.

So, if you release an object, you should not try to access it afterwards in the same scope where you previously retained (init'ed, copied) it.

Comment: Thank you :) I was just hoping to see what happens when I release and retain immediately after that. I thought It will crash. And I tried printing the value after some delay, too. Even then it shows up the proper value.

Comment: The retain/release mechanism is like a contract ensuring some things you may definitely do in your code, not defining the consequences for violating the contract.

Comment: Another example: [Calling `release` on string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769769/do-i-need-to-release-a-constant-nsstring) (`@"foo"`) will never cause them to be deleted.